# Can I have my model inherit from the Controller class in order to send many models to one Controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Essentially what I have is various account controllers (one for level 1 acc, one for level 2 acc, etc).

I would like each controller to return a profileOverview for the related account.

A profileOverview returns an object made up of data fetched from other models (eg unread messages, project status, etc). My profileOverview model essentially does the following:

```
return new ProfileOverview()
{
  NewMessages = user.Messages.Where(m => !m.ReadBy.Contains(user) && !m.IsDeleted)
    .Select(n => MessageOverview.FromDB(n)).ToList(),
  Notifications = user.Notifications.Where(n => !n.IsDeleted)
    .Select(n => Notification.FromDB(n)).ToList(),
  ProjectInformations = user.Projects.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted)
    .Select(p => Project.FromDB(p)).ToList(),
  News = user.NewsFlash.Where(n => !n.IsDeleted && n.OnStartScreen)
    .Select(n => NewsFlash.FromDB(n)).ToList()
};
```

Is this ok or do I need to be making these calls in my Account controller class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post more code. It's not even clear where this object is being returned. But, you definitely shouldn't be returning this in your Model.

Comment: Is this simply for a heads-up display on the page [e.g. notification bar]? If so, I'd be off-loading this to an AJAX call (and possibly bring in SignalR for two benefits: spead up initial page load time & introduce more real-time notifications).

Comment: @BradChristie Many thanks, I'm after looking up SignalR now and it looks like it could do the trick alright. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @ataravati The object is being returned by the various account controllers. For eg Level1AccountController returns View(new ProfileOverview())